Asymptotic Order for the Number of n-Permutations with k Inversions
Let $P(n,k)$ be the number of permutations of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ with $k$ inversions. I am attempting to find the asymptotic magnitude of $P(n,k)$ for $k=k(n)$ that may vary with $n$. To be specific, I am seeking a general result that may look like
$$
P(n,k(n))=\Theta(n^a(\log n)^b),\quad\text{when}\ k(n)\ \text{satisfies}\ [\text{some growth condition in}\ n].
$$
A natural upper bound for $P(n,k)$ is
$$
P(n,k)\leq \binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k}.
$$
This merely bounds $P(n,k)$ from the above and is not tight. In fact, I can show that $P(n,k)=\Theta(n^k)$ for all constant $k$. But I am stuck on general $k$ that may grow with $n$, such as $k(n)=n$ or $k(n)=\log n$.
Is there any existing result revealing the asymptotic order of $P(n,k)$? Any hints, references or new thoughts would be appreciated.
